# Postgres order by with multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, query, order-by

So imagine I have a result set that looks something like this:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| Id |  Date_One  |  Date_Two  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2022-05-12 | null       |
|  2 | 2022-05-13 | 2022-05-11 |
|  3 | null       | 2022-05-14 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

I would like to order the result based on earliest date first, regardless of column. Each row will have either `Date_One` or `Date_Two` populated. They will never both be null.

So the result for the above result set would be:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| Id |  Date_One  |  Date_Two  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  2 | 2022-05-13 | 2022-05-11 |
|  1 | 2022-05-12 | null       |
|  3 | null       | 2022-05-14 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

(Since Id 2 has `Date_Two` earlier than Id 1's `Date_One`).

I'm not sure how I would create my `ORDER BY` clause. My naive solution was to use `COALESCE`, but that wouldn't work for ID 2 in my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `order by least(date_one, date_two)`

The `least` function returns the lowest of two values, Coincidentally, you may use `greatest(date_one, date_two)` to get the highest value. This also works with `null`, however if both values are `null` obviously either of these functions will return `null` since there is nothing to compare.

Keep in mind that using `least` or `greatest` will also make any indexes you've created for ordering these 2 columns unusable unless you create it as an index over an immutable function using `least/greatest`. Although I am not sure that's the best move here in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm